# 4 sum time complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Here is the typical 4sum problem.
Given an array S of n integers, are there elements a, b, c, and d in S such that a + b + c + d = target? Find all unique quadruplets in the array which gives the sum of target. 

One solution I know will take O(n^3) time. But when I was analyzing the minimal time complexity, I was confused by the statement: "Since there will be O(n^4) kinds of combinations for 4 numbers, in the worst case they might all sum up to the target number and therefore we have to at least visit each of the combination once. As a result, minimal time complexity is O(n^4)." 

I know the statement is clearly wrong (after all there exists O(n^3) algorithm), but don't know why. 
 

I know this can be a stupid question... But I'm really confused by this. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot conclude from the number of combinations to the number of steps. If this would be true, sorting would take O(n!) steps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because the problem asks for all **unique** combinations of 4 numbers that give the specified sum. Let's see the details. If the quoted sentences

> Since there will be O(n^4) kinds of combinations for 4 numbers, in the
>   worst case they might all sum up to the target number and therefore we
>   have to at least visit each of the combination once. As a result,
>   minimal time complexity is O(n^4).

were true, that would mean that analogous 2-Sum problem has minimal time complexity `O(n^2)`, right? However, we all know it does not. That's because we don't have to check all pairs to find all *unique* pairs. Assume the contrary, i.e. that all pairs sum up to the specified sum, and all are unique, so we need to check them all. It means that we can find four different integers `a, b, c, d` from the array such that `a + b = s` and `c + d = s`, but also `a + c = s` and `b + d = s`. This implies `2a + b + c = 2d + b + c`, or `a = d`, and this gives `b = c`. Therefore, `(a,b) = (c,d)`, so the assumption that all pairs are unique is wrong, a contradiction. Consequently, if we processed the pair `(a,b)`, we can skip `(c,d)` because it is the same pair. And that is what algorithms with `O(n^3)` complexity do in case of 4-Sum problem, they utilize this fact either by sorting or hashing the elements of the input array at the beginning. Some clever solutions can be found [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/4sum/discuss/).

Comment: Sorry for replying late and really thanks for your explanation! So that is to say, because there won’t be o(n^4) kinds of unique combinations , the time complexity will can be better than o(n^4) right?

Comment: @Patrick Exactly. If you needed to check all `n^4` combinations then there would be no way to do better than `O(n^4)` and what you cited would be true. But fortunately, that is not needed.